# R Engine is not initializing

Tags: c#, r, r.net

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Set the folder in which R.dll locates.
    var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    var rBinPath = @"C:\R-3.0.2\bin\i386\";
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPath + Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath);
    using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet"))
    {
        // Initializes settings.
        engine.Initialize(); // After Executing this line its crashing.

        NumericVector group1 = engine.CreateNumericVector(new double[] { 30.02, 29.99, 30.11, 29.97, 30.01, 29.99 });
        engine.SetSymbol("group1", group1);
        NumericVector group2 = engine.Evaluate("group2 <- c(29.89, 29.93, 29.72, 29.98, 30.02, 29.98)").AsNumeric();

        // Test difference of mean and get the P-value.
        GenericVector testResult = engine.Evaluate("t.test(group1, group2)").AsList();
        double p = testResult["p.value"].AsNumeric().First();

        Console.WriteLine("Group1: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", group1));
        Console.WriteLine("Group2: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", group2));
        Console.WriteLine("P-value = {0:0.000}", p);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

}

Hi 
When I executed the above code it is crashing while initializing.
OS is Windows XP sp3(32 bit)
R version- R-3.0.2
using R.Net(1.5 version)

Please help me to connect to R from c#

Comment: What line it crashes on?

Comment: I need some help in this program crashing issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the engine crashes because you have some R-path error. better to read the path from windows registry.

Try something like this:

```
using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\R-core\R")){
    var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    string rBinPath = (string)registryKey.GetValue("InstallPath");
    string rVersion = (string)registryKey.GetValue("Current Version");
    rBinPath = System.Environment.Is64BitProcess ? rBinPath + "\\bin\\x64" : 
                                                     rBinPath + "\\bin\\i386";
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", 
                          envPath + Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath);
}
using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet")){
              // same code here 
}
```

Of course you should ad the right references:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using RDotNet;
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Is there any thing to replace with "SOFTWARE\R-core\R"

cause I'm getting ERROR
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

Comment: No nothing. You can check you register , launch cmd --> regedit --> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE --> SOFTWARE --> R ... Then if you don't find any key entry , you should reinstall R and check the option to set up registry during install...

Comment: Thanks very much agstudy for helping.
in my case path is as follows.
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"software\R-core\R");

But still its crashing on same initializing line.

Comment: I need some help in this program crashing issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Crash at engine.Initialize() call.
I reinstalled R for windows as administrator and registered keys in registry. R.NET works fine now even in ASP.NET application.